# Azure Data Sync Error

Tags: azure, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

I am using Windows Azure data sync agent for sync on premises database to SQL Azure DB,

I am getting following error after sync process started.

```
"Blob transfer failedInner exception: One or more errors occurred.Inner exception: 
    One or more errors occurred.

    Inner exception: The Data Transfer Service has encountered a fatal error when performing the data upload.
    Inner exception: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
    Inner exception: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
```

Any one have an idea about this error.

Comment: This looks like there is some sort of connection issue, but unfortunately there is not much detail to track down the culprit. Considering you've received a *forbidden*, could this be an issue where you need to provide a set of keys to access the remote DB? The *address* of the remote DB seems okay, considering you're not seeing the **remote name cannot be resolved issue** (described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/52a778ac-055b-49a0-b0f5-3954f8dce747/data-transfer-service-has-encountered-a-fatal-error-when-performing-the-data-upload?forum=ssdsgetstarted)).

Comment: Thank you for the information, this setup was working fine earlier, suddenly this strange error occurred, do you have a suggestion for me to do a workaround ?

Comment: Ah, that bit of information would be helpful in the question and makes me wonder if there is possibly more information that you could add to the question. Currently, the fact that it was working and now isn't working is not very helpful, but it *would* be helpful if you could describe any changes that were made between when it was working and when it started failing.